# How can I color rows in datagridview with condition C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, colors, row

I want with a condition :

- all rows have `bool_badge =0`  : color with **RED**
- all rows have `bool_badge=1`   : color with **ForestGreen**

I have a code Correct BUT just when i click for a cell specific

My code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {              
            int row = this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            string valeur = dataGridView1[2, row].Value.ToString();

            if (valeur == "0")
            {
                dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.ForestGreen;
            }
        }
```

The Result :
1) [image]`

2)  [image]

But I want when i execute my application , the test begin if bool_badge 0 or 1, and i have for all the gridview : color RED or ForestGreen ,

I try this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {                
            string valeur = dataGridView1[2, i].Value.ToString();

            if (valeur == "0")
            {
                dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.ForestGreen;
            }
        }
```

But i have ERROR!

this is :

[image]

How can i fix it?

Very thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Datagridview's `Cell_Formatting` event.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText == "bool_badge" && dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value != null) 
         // if the column is bool_badge and check null value for the extra row at dgv
            {
                    if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() == "0")
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() == "1")
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen;
                    }
            }
        }
```

**Result** will be,

[image]

Hope helps,

Comment: Thanks,

I try it, but don't have any result! any color! just DataGridView with data 

Are you missing something else?

Comment: @devtunis Don't copy directly. Set cell formatting at the design. Datagridview-> press f4 -> press lightining button -> find cell fotmatting evet and double click. If you do with this way already. Did you debug?

Comment: I set CellFormatting with double click,

and I make the code in

private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)

But nothing! no color! just the display DataGridView with data

Comment: @devtunis Debug please put breakpoint to CellFormatting event. There are 3 if, find out why they return false.

Comment: Sorry I make a mistake,
Your Code is CORRECT!!

Very very thanks!!!
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You should use .Rows and .Cells properties.

```
string valeur = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks,

but when i execute my application, no color appear! just display of datagridview with data,

and when i click to specific CELL, i have same ERROR :

The NullReferenceException was unhandled

Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 0):

For helping you debugging don't do Value.ToString(); just

```
 var value = dataGridView_XXX.Rows[rowNumber].Cells[i].value;
```

And

```
if (value == null) display your row/column index
else dataGridView_XXX.Rows[rowNumber].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = xxx;
```