# Change row color in DataGridView based on column date

Tags: c#, datagridview, rows

I have got a `DataGridView` with several columns, one being the "Calibration Due Date". I'm looking for a way to change the color of a row to RED if the calibration due date has passed, and to BLUE if there is less than one month until the calibration due date.

I have tried the following code which didn't do anything:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridView row in instrumentsDataGridView.Rows)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var expirationDate = DateTime.Parse(instrumentsDataGridView.Columns["CalibrationDue"].ToString());
        var Month = expirationDate.AddDays(-30);

        if (now > Month && now < expirationDate)
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        else if (now > expirationDate)
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Both red and blue colors not appearing ?

Comment: Dint your code output any error ?

Comment: @JonesJoseph neither colour is appearing, and no errors were shown

Comment: Shouldnt it be `DataGridViewRow row in instrumentsDataGridView.Rows` in the foreach statement? Instead of just `DataGridView`?

Comment: @Sanaa Are the value of `now`, `month` and `expirationDate` are correct, Did you check the values at debug? Are the formats same? And you should use  `CellFormatting` event instead of use foreach loop. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378386/how-can-i-color-rows-in-datagridview-with-condition-c-sharp/40378840#40378840)

Comment: Use an `else` block and put some other color there. Check if atleast that color is being applied. If yes, then there is a mistake in your condition

Comment: @JonesJoseph Tried that, still no colour.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in the `CellFormatting` event:

```
private void DataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == instrumentsDataGridView.Columns["CalibrationDue"].Index)
    {
        if (e.Value == null)
            return;

        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var expirationDate = (DateTime)e.Value;
        var month = expirationDate.AddDays(-30);

        var row = instrumentsDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        if (now > month && now < expirationDate)
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        else if (now > expirationDate)
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sanaa if you didn't add the CellFormatting event handler, you can check  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492149.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DataGridViewRow.Cells`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.cells) Property:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now, thirtyDaysAgo = now.AddDays(-30), expirationDate;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in instrumentsDataGridView.Rows)
{
    string cellText = row.Cells["CalibrationDue"].Value + "";

    if (DateTime.TryParse(cellText, out expirationDate))
    {
        if (expirationDate < now)
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        else if (expirationDate > thirtyDaysAgo)
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that, still no colours. I think I maybe need to put the code somewhere else and not the form load function?

Comment: @Sanaa it will have to be after the rows are added, and you can use the debugger to see if the color statements are reached.

Answer (score 0):

I was putting the code in the wrong place. I've put the following code into another form's source code (form for entering details into the `DataGridView`) and it is now working:

```
 DateTime now = DateTime.Now, thirtyDaysAgo = now.AddDays(-30), expirationDate;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in form.instrumentsDataGridView.Rows)
        {
            string cellText = row.Cells["CalibrationDue"].Value + "";

            if (DateTime.TryParse(cellText, out expirationDate))
            {
                if (expirationDate < now)
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                else if (expirationDate > thirtyDaysAgo)
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.PaleTurquoise;
            }
        }
```