# How to change the color of a Cell in a DataGridView if date is 1 month before what is in the cell?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, datagridview, colors

I'v been looking through a LOT of websites and i did not find any awnser,
So let's say I have a DataGridView with a Column and the Rows are (assuming today's date is `21/05/2019` (`dd/mm/yyyy`))

- 22/05/2019
- 22/04/2019
- 21/01/2019

So I want the first one to be in red (because its 1 day off today's date)
I want the second one to be in orange (because it entered the -1 month mark)
And the last one should be normal because its far from -1 month.

I've tryed this:

```
var dateminusonemonth = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);   
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgproduit.Rows)
if (Convert.ToString(dateminusonemonth) = txtboxdatecontrole.Text)
{
     row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

But it doesn't work at all and I dont know where to look at...

EDIT : This is what i want, but i cant get it to work [Change row color in DataGridView based on column date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40749012/change-row-color-in-datagridview-based-on-column-date)

EDIT : It worked ! with this code :

```
 DateTime now = DateTime.Now, thirtyDaysAgo = now.AddDays(-30), expirationDate;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgproduit.Rows)
        {
            string cellText = row.Cells["datecontrole"].Value + "";

            if (DateTime.TryParse(cellText, out expirationDate))
            {
                if (expirationDate < now)
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
                else if (expirationDate > thirtyDaysAgo)
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a = sign? ==
Also see what is the result from Convert.ToString(dateminusomonth) it maybe different from you text value.

Comment: This is something you usually do in the `CellFormatting` event. A DataGrid is not a DataGridView. It appears you're using the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what exactly you need but I will try.

```
var dateminusonemonth = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgproduit.Rows)
        {
            DateTime DateToComapre = Datetime.Parse(row.Cells[Cell with you Date to Comapre].value); //Date format must match!
            if (DateTime.Now < DateToCompare)
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else if (dateminusonemonth < DateToCompare && DateToCompare < DateTime.Now)
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;
            }
            else
            {
                 drow.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Empty;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try with row.Cells[x].value;

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have sequences of items, LINQ is your best friend

Assuming the column that shows the dates that you want to color is `columnDate`

```
DataGridViewColumn columnDate = ...
DataGridView myDataGridView = ...

var dateCells = myDataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(row => row.Cells[columnDate.Name])
    .Select(dateCell => new
    {
        DataGridViewCell = dateCell,
        Date = DateTime.Parse(dateCell.Value.ToString()).Date,
    });
```

So Date contains the Date part of the displayed value in the DateCell. If you don't want to compare on Date, but on a TimeSpan of 24 hours, you should remember the DateTime.

```
Date = DateTime.Parse(dateCell.Value.ToString());
```

Now to get the cells that you want to colorize:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

// The cells that have a date between (today - 1 day) and (today + 1 day) should be red:
var todayMinus1Day = today.AddDays(-1);
var todayPlus1Day = today.AddDays(+1);
var todayMinus1Month = today.AddMonths(-1);
var todayPlus1Month = today.AddMonths(+1)

 foreach (var cell in dateCells)
 {
     if (todayMinus1Month <= cell.Date && cell.Date <= todayPlus1Month)
     {
         // either orange or red: not default:
         cell.DataGridViewCell.Style = cell.DataGridViewCell.GetInheritedStyle();
         cell.DataGridViewCell.Style.BackColor =
             (todayMinums1Day <= cell.Date && cell.Date <= todayPlus1Day) ?
               Color.Red : Color.Orange;
     }
     else
     {   // use the inherited style = set the cell style to null
         cell.DataGridViewCell.Style = null;
     }
}
```